# Getting UPTIME from port number in UNIX command

Tags: shell, unix

Is it possible to get the server UPTIME from mentioning PORT number or Process ID in UNIX command? Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From port - I don't think so.

From process ID :

```
ps -eo pid,etime | grep " 1 " | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

Example:

```
root@localhost:~[0]$ ps -eo pid,etime | grep " 1 " | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
01:16:10
root@localhost:~[0]$
```

But you can use `uptime` command.